# Неверное время DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

Здравствуйте. Я делаю систему оповещений и есть задача сделать следующее: узнать, когда пришло уведомление. То есть: 1 минуту назад/16 часов назад и т.д. Я сделал алгоритм, но показывает неверное время. Тестовое оповещение было отправлено 5 минут назад, но показывает 9 часов назад. Почему?
Алгоритм скрипта:

1. Получение старой временой метки из БД.
2. Получение текущего времени пользователя.
3. Получение разницы между этими метками.
4. Отображение.

Вот код:

```
 $fromdb = '1503737539'; //Допустим, что тут мы получили время из БД. 
//Этот timestamp - 5 минут ранее моего текущего времени.

    $curr = new DateTime();
    $got2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$fromdb));
    $interval = $curr->diff($got2);
    echo $interval->format('%d')." days ".$interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes ".$interval->format('%s')." Seconds";
```

Comment: Почти наверняка проблема в часовой зоне

Comment: `new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$fromdb));` время-то где? И вообще `DateTime::setTimestamp`

Comment: Если Вы получаете время из БД, то оттуда же получайте и текущее время

Answer (score 0):

```
$fromdb = '1503762701'; 

$curr = new DateTime();
$got2 = new DateTime();
$got2->setTimestamp($fromdb);

$interval = $curr->diff($got2);
echo $interval->format("Прошло: %d дней, %h часов, %i минут и %s секунд\n");
```

Вы переводили unix время в формат год, месяц, день но не указывали часы, минуты и секунды